# SpriteKit not loading Atlas with tga pics

Tags: sprite-kit

I made a simple program that uses a texture atlas to load an animation on the screen. When I used an atlas with png images everything worked fine. However when I tried using another atlas that used tga images all I got was the white box with the red x. Whats going on? Do SpriteKit atlases not support the tga format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKTextureAtlas` does not support Truevision's TGA format. I suggest you convert the TGA images to one of the supported file formats: PNG, JPEG, TIFF, BMP, or GIF.